# Why history.js uses setInterval(.., 250)?

Tags: javascript, performance, setinterval, history.js, html5-history

From what I understand [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) is a polyfill for [HTML5 History/State APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Therefore, on modern browsers, it should simply use [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.onpopstate) for listening to URL changes. So, **why on latest Chrome I can see timer firing every 250ms?** It seems so wasteful and triggers garbage collector every few seconds.

Check out this official [History.js demo](http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/).

[image: History.js demo page firing timer every 250ms]

Comment: Why do not you use the native JS?

Comment: @RomanGorbatko We need to support [IE9 and older android browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history). Therefore, using a polyfill is required (isn't it?).

Comment: i didnt get any Timer Fired Records in chrome latest

Comment: @NavaRajan I've tested it on both Canary and Stable on OSX and Windows. Please make sure that you have clicked 'Record' on the timeline tab.

Comment: As best as I can tell, this is related to [`History.busy`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.js#L1332) which is responsible for flushing a queue of tasks. I've never used or worked on history.js, so I'm not sure why this is necessary (or *if* it is necessary to have running *constantly*). You could change `History.options.busyDelay` to a higher millisecond value to slow the interval, but you should do extensive cross-browser testing to see if anything breaks.

Comment: I'm noticing this as well. Currently using Chrome 29. My webapp is loads a LOT on each page, and so I think it's setInterval

Comment: Did you find the reason of why this is happening even on HTML5 compatible browsers?
Based on the script command, it's supposed to be fired for uncompatible browsers like IE < 10

Comment: @MykaEyl Nope, as you can see there is no answer to this question yet. Someone will have to dig into history.js code to find this out. However, I choose to believe that this has some reasonable explanation, it would be a pretty huge bug otherwise and this is a very popular library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the History.js code, but reading through it, I believe @apsillers is correct.

It is configured to an interval of 250ms between queue items. Some of the queued functions in that queue require grabbing the History state. These items force the flushing to pause by calling it to be busy.

As to why this happens in HTML5 browsers also to me seems is that History.JS doesn't just toggle a switch if it's HTML5 and then do nothing. On their [github](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) it states one of their Aims to be:

> Provide a cross-compatible experience for all HTML5 Browsers (they all implement the HTML5 History API a little bit differently causing different behaviours and sometimes bugs - History.js fixes this ensuring the experience is as expected / the same / great throughout the HTML5 browsers)

If History.js is still doing even some work that involves queueing, I'd guess they'd use the busy timeout.